# Does elastic TSDS support nested fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series, elastic-stack

I am reading the documentation for timeseries datastreams, because I wanted to use it for my timeseries data due to the saved memory space. However, I am dealing with nested fields. Are they supported for TSDS?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tsds.html